# Border in autocomplete dropdown menu

Tags: android, autocomplete, border

I have a problem. I don't know how remove border and shadow of autocomplete dropdown menu. Anybody help me?

[image]

I need to dropdown menu was transparent, without gray edges and of the lines

Comment: Hello. Have you solved this problem? May I ask you for the solution?

Comment: I made a clear background from drop-down menu, and under it put an empty ListView, this emulated the result that I need

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found solution: add `android:popupBackground="@null"` to `AutoCompleteTextView` tag